# Typescript types definitions - inheritance

Tags: typescript, types, interface, typescript-typings

I have a typescript interface that represent my data in database, like :

```
interface Foo {
  bar: {
    fish: {
       _id: string,
       name: string,
    }[],
  },

  starwars: string[],
}
```

I would like to be able to reference parts of this interface. In the following example, I want to pass the data behind the key `fish` as parameters.

I succedded to make it work doing :

```
interface Fish {
  _id: string,
  name: string,
}

interface Foo {
  bar: {
    fish: Fish[],
  },

  starwars: string[],
}

function killTheFish(fish: Fish) { ... }
```

But I would prefer doing something like :

```
type Fish = Foo.bar.fish;
```

Do you know any way to reference a part of an interface ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you want [lookup types, aka indexed access types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types).  It uses the square bracket notation instead of dot notation (which would collide with namespaces):

```
type FishArray = Foo["bar"]["fish"]
/*
type FishArray = {
    _id: string;
    name: string;
}[]
*/

type Fish = Foo["bar"]["fish"][number];
/* type Fish = {
    _id: string;
    name: string;
} */
```

If you have a property-having type `T` and a keylike type `K` which is part of the keys of `T` (`K extends keyof T`), then `T[K]` is the type of the property of `T` at that key `K`.  So `Foo["bar"]["fish"]` is the type you get if you have a `foo` object of type `Foo` and read `foo.bar.fish`.

That's an array in your example; if you want the element type, you can get that. Arrays have a numeric [index signature](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types), so if you have a key of type `number`, then you'll get the element type.  So `Foo["bar"]["fish"][number]` is that element type.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyRyARnFAFw4HG3IzADOAFlXoXZwPrAAmVjMFFABzADQ1OdEHAC2EAUNESOnAL4BtALoraalZKKDyAd3KNFwkCO0H8a5AQJgAngAcUqJswCCUKHAuyAC8aJgaAERkUBFakQwssQQA9ABUzu6e3n4BQaHstDz8yIJWIgDchsgy8pailfbaBKnJTviuHmjeIWHokdGx8d6DIACusiTQWg1pyB1ZLD0FxEV11g20NQolSusEDi1AA)

Comment: Magnificent. Note that when there are arrays of same elements, example of syntax is : `Foo['bar'][0]['obiwan'][0]['kenobi']`

Answer (score 1):

Without further ado - we can access mapped type member types by index/key using lookup type syntax `['prop']`

```
type FishArr = Foo['bar']['fish'];
```

Array type is also mapped type `Array<X> = {[k:number]: X}`, so all keys have a type `number`, then by the same way we take a member type from any other mapped type, we can use `number` for array type element

```
type Fish = Foo['bar']['fish'][number];
```